# php://input confusing array information

Tags: php, base64

I have a base64 text, which is huge, posted from Ajax.  In console, I can see the code, and if i copy and paste it into a base64 image converter it works fine.

In PHP `$_POST` is always empty, but `php://input` shows all the information, which is a JSON with four parts within the array.  Under the 'imgData' part, the image binary code is complete and works, but if I do this:

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
(A) print_r($data); // Shows all the image data under [imgData]

(B) print_r($data->imgData); //  Only shows a small part of the image data
```

Here is an example of the output (A):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [switch] => addImage
    [table] => tbl_images
    [propid] => 
    [imgData] => data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAAH0AAAAoAAAA
```

Here is the exmaple output (B):

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAA
```

But (B) is only part of the data?   Any reason for this ?

**UPDATE**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
(A) var_dump($data);

(B) var_dump($data->imgData);
```

The above are now equal and give the same string sizes.

When I put this into a SQL query:

```
        $detail = "Property_Id, Image_Data ) VALUES ( 213, " . $data->imgData;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " ( " . $detail . " )";
        echo $sql;
        $addQ = $mysqli->query($sql);

        echo 'image added';

        print_r($mysqli->error);
    } else {
        echo "No params added";
    }
```

It still does not show the end of the $sql string ?

Comment: Try the same thing with `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and compare the length of the string as output by `var_dump` (`string (...) "..."`). This seems basically impossible to be a real issue, probably just debug/display issues for some reason.

Comment: @deceze Thank you.  The var_dump did make both match, but it still loses the last part of the string, when I put it to use.  I have updated the above question.   When I use the `$data->imgData` in a query string for mySQL, it misses the last part of it ?

Comment: Please show *exactly* what you're seeing! Is it possible that you have xdebug or something similar installed which simply limits the output of debug functions like `var_dump`?